# Windows 10 install features and developer mode offline

Tags: windows-10, .net-3.5, windows-subsystem-for-linux, legacy, missing-features

I need to install OFFLINE features of Windows like "LegacyCompoents", "DirectPlay", ".NET Framework 3.5", "Windows Subsystem Linux" and "Developer Mode" on Windows 10 (Home/Pro x64 1909).

Online, it works fine with that (run as admin, obviously):

```
cls
@echo off
cd /d "%~dp0"

reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModelUnlock" /t REG_DWORD /v "AllowDevelopmentWithoutDevLicense" /d "1" /f >nul
dism /online /add-capability /capabilityname:Tools.DeveloperMode.Core~~~~0.0.1.0 /norestart
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFx3 /norestart
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:LegacyComponents /norestart
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:DirectPlay /norestart
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux /norestart

pause
exit
```

But offline, I can't get packages. So as to, I tried to upgrade an offline image to find packages in a folder like "/sources/sxs".

I unpack my ".iso" image of Windows 10. This command gives me the number of the "Pro" installation = 6.

```
dism /get-imageinfo /imagefile:"%cd%\Windows 10 x64\sources\install.wim"
```

I mount the image.

```
if not exist "C:\test\offline" mkdir "C:\test\offline"
dism /mount-image /imagefile:"%cd%\Windows 10 x64\sources\install.wim" /index:6 /mountdir:"C:\test\offline"
```

Until here, it works. But just after that, the Developer Mode fails.

```
dism /image:"C:\test\offline" /add-capability /capabilityname:Tools.DeveloperMode.Core~~~~0.0.1.0 /logpath:"%~dpn0.log"
```

> Error: 0x800f081f The source files could not be found.
>   Use the "Source" option to specify the location of the files that are required to restore the feature. For more information on specifying a source location, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=243077.

After that, .NET Framework 3.5 fails too, same error code.

```
dism /image:C:\test\offline /enable-feature /featurename:NetFx3 /logpath:"%~dpn0.log"
```

Otherwise, LegacyComponent, DirectPlay and Linux work fine.

```
dism /image:C:\test\offline /enable-feature /featurename:LegacyComponents
dism /image:C:\test\offline /enable-feature /featurename:DirectPlay
dism /image:C:\test\offline /enable-feature /featurename:Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
```

After that, I unmount the image, but I can't find the downloaded packages.

```
dism /unmount-image /mountdir:"C:\test\offline" /commit
```

My wish is to get ".cab" packages and to be able to install them just with a script like that:

```
cls
@echo off
cd /d "%~dp0"

reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModelUnlock" /t REG_DWORD /v "AllowDevelopmentWithoutDevLicense" /d "1" /f >nul
dism /online /add-capability /capabilityname:Tools.DeveloperMode.Core~~~~0.0.1.0 /limitaccess /source:"%cd%\Packages" /logpath:"%~dpn0.log" /norestart
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFx3           /limitaccess /source:"%cd%\Packages" /logpath:"%~dpn0.log" /norestart
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:LegacyComponents /limitaccess /source:"%cd%\Packages" /logpath:"%~dpn0.log" /norestart
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:DirectPlay       /limitaccess /source:"%cd%\Packages" /logpath:"%~dpn0.log" /norestart
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux /limitaccess /source:"%cd%\Packages" /logpath:"%~dpn0.log" /norestart

echo.
timeout 5
del /f /q "%~dpn0.log"
```

Can you help me, please?

Best regards,

Answer (score 2):

I guess you already found the solution since it's an old post. I will write it down in case somebody else is looking for it.

You need to download the **Features on Demand** Windows 10 ISO file (you'll need a Visual Studio Subscription for this) and then extract the following packages:

```
Microsoft-OneCore-DeveloperMode-Desktop-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~.cab
Microsoft-WebDriver-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~.cab
```

Before installing the package, enable developer mode by setting the following DWORD key to 1:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModelUnlock\AllowDevelopmentWithoutDevLicense
```

The package can be installed with the following command:

```
dism /online /add-capability /capabilityname:Tools.DeveloperMode.Core~~~~0.0.1.0 /limitaccess /source:"C:\path\to\folder" /norestart
```

I have tested this on a domain joined computer without access to Windows Update

**(WSUS server is configured via GPO and Dual Scan is disabled).**

Comment: Thank you VERY much ;)
I didn't find otherwise I would have post it here...